# Header redirecting function error for online if encoding utf-8

Tags: php, encoding, utf-8

I have a PHP file which is saved as encoding utf-8. The file has header redirecting function without any white space or html above it . If run it in local machine not any problem. But if run in online showing error:

> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by
>   (output started at /home/nikahservi/public_html/Admin/Home.php:1) in
>   /home/nikahservi/public_html/Admin/Home.php on line 1

I tried in three way the code is below: please help me.

```
1)
<?php header("Location:index.php");exit();?>

2)
<?php header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
header("Location:index.php");exit();?>

3)
<?php header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate");header("Expires: Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT");header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
header("Location:index.php");exit();?>
```

Comment: What do you mean "run online?" Is it a hosting service? Does it append extra data to your pages?

Comment: Did you use echo or print before the headers code?

Comment: no echo or nothing more.online means  the server from where websites are running by internet. The  server which is not from my computer.

Comment: Check for a BOM at the beginning of Home.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found the solution by changing my default Notepad of windows to Notepad++. The error was created by virus in Notepad. The virus was giving hidden value to the notepad. So now everything is clear.

Answer (score 0):

Accidental whitespace, often at the beginning or end of files, like this:

```
THERE SHOULD BE NO BLANK SPACES HERE
<?php  

   echo "your code here";

?>
DO CHECK FOR BLANK SPACES HERE AS WELL; THIS LINE (blank line) SHOULD NOT EXIST.
```

If this is not your case then,then you can use [ob_start](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php) for output buffering like below:

**Possible Solution 2:**

```
<?php
  ob_start();

  // code 

 ob_end_flush();
?>
```

OR

- You should have a space after the `:` so it reads `"Location:
  http://foo"`
- It's not valid to use a relative URL in a `Location`
  header, you should form an absolute URL like
  `http://www.example.com/some/path.php`

Comment: I am 100% sure. there was no white space. because I tried it in singe line.

Comment: I tried this space after : <?php ob_start();header("Location: index.php");exit();ob_end_flush();?>

Comment: i tried this also <?php ob_start();header("Location: http://www.yaseennikahservice.com/index.php");exit();ob_end_flush();?>

Comment: from above link copy and paste the code. it shows not send